# Oracle sum() column number by row

Tags: sql, oracle11g, count

I'm trying to do a view where I count the numbers in eache column but by row. What I've got so far is this:

```
 create OR REPLACE view view_test as                                                                                        
  select distinct(estadodebicicleta.n_bicicleta) as bicicleta_ID, count(estadodebicicleta.guiador) + count(estadodebicicleta.celin) as dmgLVL, estadodebicicleta.guiador, estadodebicicleta.celin, estadodebicicleta.dt_verificacao as data_avaliacao from estadodebicicleta
    group by estadodebicicleta.n_bicicleta, estadodebicicleta.dt_verificacao, estadodebicicleta.guiador, estadodebicicleta.celin 
      order by dmgLVL;
```

in which gives this outcome:

[image]

which  is wrong. What I want to do is this:

[image]

Any idea on what I'm missing? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. It always applies to **all** columns of the select list.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query formatted and using table aliases and removing the unnecessary `distinct`:

```
select b.n_bicicleta as bicicleta_ID,
       count(b.guiador) + count(b.celin) as dmgLVL, b.guiador, b.celin,
       b.dt_verificacao as data_avaliacao
from estadodebicicleta b
group by b.n_bicicleta, b.dt_verificacao, b.guiador, b.celin 
order by dmgLVL;
```

The aggregation doesn't make sense, given your desired results.  Perhaps this will do what you want:

```
select b.n_bicicleta as bicicleta_ID,
       (b.guiador + b.celin) as dmgLVL, b.guiador, b.celin,
       b.dt_verificacao as data_avaliacao
from estadodebicicleta b
order by dmgLVL;
```

Comment: Sorry I should've said that I use the distinc because this view gets the results from a table in which `n_bicicleta` is not unique, so I need to get only 1 set of results from each UNIQUE n_bicicleta. I'm also doing `max(dt_verificacao)` to get the last date of evaluation it got for that unique ID

Answer (score 0):

Been messing with my code and found an answer:

```
create or replace view dados_bicicleta_estados as 
    SELECT edb.n_bicicleta, (edb.guiador + edb.selim + edb.corrente + edb.tfrontal + edb.ttraseiro + edb.pfrontal + edb.ptraseiro + edb.pedais) as dmgLVL, edb.guiador, edb.selim, edb.corrente, edb.tfrontal, edb.ttraseiro, edb.pfrontal, edb.ptraseiro, edb.pedais, edb.dt_verificacao as data_avaliacao
    FROM estadodebicicleta edb
    INNER JOIN (SELECT n_bicicleta, MAX(dt_verificacao) AS MaxDateTime
                  FROM estadodebicicleta
                    GROUP BY n_bicicleta) groupededb 
    ON edb.n_bicicleta = groupededb.n_bicicleta 
    AND edb.dt_verificacao = groupededb.MaxDateTime
    ORDER BY DMGLVL DESC;
```

This gives exacly what I want. And Thanks for helping everyone.